# Criterion of highly-ranked answer

Tags: support

I'm checking [IMPACT] of the user-profile page. It says (bold by me)

> Estimated number of times people viewed your helpful posts (based on
>   page views of your questions and questions where you wrote
>   **highly-ranked answers**)

So my question is what's the criterion of highly-ranked answer? Over +5 or something else?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks. I got it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The criteria for the statistic is explained in [We're working on a new stat to help convey the reach of your posts here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here) as indicated by [Robert Longson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1038015/robert-longson). From that post:

> - **Answers** - Views of the parent question for answers that are:
>
>   - Non-deleted AND
>   - Score > 0 AND
>   - Also meets one or more of the following criteria:
>
>     - In the top 3 answers OR
>     - Is the Accepted Answer OR
>     - Score at least 5 OR
>     - Has at least 20% of the total vote count

A lot of the weirdness and the volatility of this number is discussed on MSE in under the tag [People Reached](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/people-reached)